# Hide Entire given rows if a specified cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie in VBA coding.

I am trying to achieve that inside my function

```
sub Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

where it checks some specified cells value change to run a given macro. The additional macro that i want to add is that when ever cell a62 is Empty, it will hide rows a56:a61. and consecutively if a82 is empty, it will hide rows a78:a82.

i have the following code but it only hides the rows from the first empty cell until end of sheet.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 4 To 800
    If Sheets("Results").Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
      Rows(i & ":" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True
      Rows("1:" & i - 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit sir @james Z

Comment: But what cell change do you want to trigger the event? "A62" and "A82"? Each of them becoming empty will hide the corresponding rows, but if they will have a value, should the rows in discussion become visible? If this two cells will trigger the event, I think no iteration is necessary.

Comment: Only if those cells are empty. if They have values then rows should be visible

Comment: What will trigger the code you posted, and what will trigger the other two that you require? A manual change in one or more cells or a change by formula? Isn't it enough just to hide or show the row where this change will happen if it doesn't apply to the two extra requirements?

Comment: If the Cells are blank, so i have sub code `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) ` inside the "Results" sheet. Results sheet contain Three Pivot tables connected by a Slicer. so right now , what i have is when i select an item in that Slicer, it will of course change the values in the three Pivot table reports, which will now trigger `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) ` ... this code will check if there are any changes in any of the cell in the given range in the area of the first pivot, one of which includes the item in the slicer. so my goal is

Comment: in addition to this, i hope to hide the rows where the 2nd and 3rd pivot tables are located, "if the cells  "A62" and "A82" are empty". so A62 is in the area of 2nd Pivot , while A82 is for the 3rd. Hence, if A62 is empty, hide only the 2nd pivot table, if A82 is empty hide only the 3rd pivot table. if both are empty, both pivot table rows will be hidden.

Comment: wheew i hope i am not stressing you too much on this.

Comment: If for "A82" condition will hide "A78:A82", you can never change "A82" again, being hidden... I will prepare an answer, but able to hide "A78:A81" and you will think about the implication and adapt it according to your needs...

Comment: Please, check the answer code and send some feedback. Please, also confirm that the cells change is done manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check the next event code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$A$62" Or Target.Address = "$A$82" Then
        Select Case Target.Address
            Case "$A$62"
                If Target.Value = "" Then
                    Range("A56:A61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Else
                    Range("A56:A61").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            Case "$A$82"
                If Target.Value = "" Then
                    Range("A78:A81").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Else
                    Range("A78:A81").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
        End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

It will be triggered only if you MANUALLY change the value of one of the two required cells.

If their value is the result of a formula, `Worksheet_Calculate` event must be used, but in a different way. This event does not have any argument (no Target) and you must check the two cells in discussion and act according to their value, independent if they were changed or not when the Calculate event is triggered. If this is the case, I can post such an event code, too.

**Edited:**

For the version which does not involve the manual changing of the values, please copy this event code in the sheet code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Me.Range("A62").Value = "" Then
        Me.Range("A56:A61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Me.Range("A56:A61").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Me.Range("A82").Value = "" Then
        Me.Range("A78:A82").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Me.Range("A78:A82").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    'Edited:
    'The part for both analyzed ranges being empty:
    If Me.Range("A62").Value = "" And _
                     Me.Range("A82").Value = "" Then
        'Do here what you need...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!!! i am expecting this to work cause it somehow resembles my current  existing code shown below . The value of the two required cells will change as a result of Pivot Table report Filter. So if the cells are empty, meaning the pivot table report is empty. so i guess it is Manually, no formula included and not triggered by VBA code.   i tried to nest this inside my existing `Worksheet_Change` code but not only it does not work, now it's even stopping my existing code to work. so i think there's just very basic item here that i am missing.

Comment: Thank you so much kind sir!! here is my existing code :         `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b1:p5")) Is Nothing Then


  
    'here lies my code to unhide all previously hidden rows
    
  ' and here to hide all rows below the first pivot table that are blank.


' then i have a code here to format a specific cell's number to date if it is date and number if column is number
  
    End If

End If


End Sub
`

Comment: So i tried it sir @faneDuru, the Pivot refresh is not considered as Manually.. so yeah, it won't work using that code as you've mentioned. but i wonder because i use the same sub function with my current code and it's working. hmmm.. but it did work when i try updating the cell manually via hardocoding

Comment: @BoyDespasito: I asked about this issue and I also specified it in my answer text. I will prepare a solution which to use `Calculation` event. I will post it in some minutes...

Comment: @BoyDespasito:  I edited the answer and posted the variant which should work without manually changing the values. It certainly works if the value is changed by using a formula, but I did not test it for the case of a Pivot Table. Theoretically, it should trigger the Calculate even, which would be enough for the code to run as necessary. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Sir @FaneDuru, i cant express enough how thankful i am for your wonder! Thank you so much!  it worked! and i am also wondering if it possible for me to add another `Else` case in that code where if the two given cells are Blank, i will hide additiional Range. :D although you can ignore this, just hoping you can have a way of it easier . but then again, thank you very much! really appreciate it.

Comment: @BoyDespasito: Glad I could help! Your new request is very easy to be solved. It would be enough to add such a condition of the code end. In fact, i will edit the code and add this part...

Comment: you are astounding sir!!! i wish i could be friends with you personally. i will always be in debt of you in this learning journey that i am taking!